# How to install the Zabbix Agent with different Ports (not 10050 and 10051)

Tags: zabbix

My question: How to install the Zabbix Agent with different Ports?

Comment: You should consider reading the documentation

Comment: Your advice helps ample little my friend ...

Answer (score 0):

Change`ListenPort` parameter in the [agent daemon configuration file](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_agentd). Note that agent uses 10050 by default, not 10051 - the second one is the default server port.

Comment: I did this. This is the error: 

Error 1053: The Zabbix Agent service failed to start due to the following error: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. 

Windows could not start the Zabbix Agent service on Local Computer.

Comment: What is the exact line you modified?

Answer (score 0):

for linux server :

in the file "zabbix_agentd.conf" you can see (near line 99) the comment line like below :

```
vim ZABBIX_AGENTD_CONFIGFILES_ADDRESS/zabbix_agentd.conf
# ListenPort=10050
```

uncomment the line and change it to your desired port like :

```
ListenPort=10060
```

then restart your zabbix agentd

for zabbix server you can uncomment and edit below line (12):

```
vim YOUR_ZABBIX_SERVER_CONFIGFILES_ADDRESS/zabbix_server.conf
# ListenPort=10051
```

to your desired port :

```
ListenPort=10061
```

and save file. then restart your zabbix server

also for windows , the steps is like above and you can edit files